# Chrome HTML5 field validation message disappears under the dom?

Tags: forms, html, validation, google-chrome

I am dealing with html5 forms and I have a field with a required attribute set. When the user wants to submit the form, chrome displays the validation message, that the field must not be empty. Strangely, this message seems to slip under the other html markup. I dont think I have any css set that could cause this.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

http://www.abload.de/img/errorogbcv.png

Comment: I do not have this in firefox

Comment: figured it out... i was an overflow:hidden issue - interesting :)

Comment: Alex, you should probably write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the html5 validation message was cut off/ under the dom due to overflow:hidden.